# Nested list comprehensions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, nested, list-comprehension

I am following this [Haskell tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com) and am on the higher order functions section. It defines a function called chain as:

```
chain :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]
chain 1 = [1]
chain n
    | even n = n:chain (n `div` 2)
    | odd n = n:chain (n * 3 + 1)
```

There is an exercise to find number of "chains" that have a length longer than 15. They do so like this:

```
numLongChains :: Int  
numLongChains = length (filter isLong (map chain [1..100]))  
    where isLong xs = length xs > 15
```

I am trying to come up with a list comprehension that instead of giving me the number of chains gives me a list of chains that are longer than 15 from [1..100]. My closest attempt so far looks like:

```
[ [ a | a <- chain b, length a > 15] | b <- [1..100]]
```

but I get:

```
<interactive>:9:14:
No instance for (Integral [a0]) arising from a use of `chain'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Integral [a0])
In the expression: chain b
In a stmt of a list comprehension: a <- chain b
In the expression: [a | a <- chain b, length a > 15]

<interactive>:9:45:
    No instance for (Enum [a0])
      arising from the arithmetic sequence `1 .. 100'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Enum [a0])
    In the expression: [1 .. 100]
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: b <- [1 .. 100]
    In the expression:
      [[a | a <- chain b, length a > 15] | b <- [1 .. 100]]

<interactive>:9:46:
    No instance for (Num [a0]) arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [a0])
    In the expression: 1
    In the expression: [1 .. 100]
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: b <- [1 .. 100]
```

Am I even close? I do want to solve this problem using a nested comprehension for the sake of learning despite the possible better ways to approach this.

Comment: came here at exactly the same place in the tutorial!

Answer (score 5):

You're close. You're looking for:

```
[ a | b <- [1..10], let a = chain b, length a > 15 ]
```

The expression

```
[ [ a | a <- chain b, length a > 15] | b <- [1..100]]
```

has type:

```
Integral [a] => [[[a]]]
```

which is clearly not what you want, but because of Haskell's polymorphic numeric literals, it *could* possibly type check if the correct definition were in place.

In this case `b` is inferred to be a list of some type, and that is why you see the error:

```
No instance for (Integral [a0]) ...
```

Here is a complete run down on how the types are inferred.

1. from `b <- [1..100]` we can infer `Enum b` is a constraint
2. from the call `chain b` we can infer `Integral b` is a constraint
3. from `a <- chain b` we can infer `a` and `b` have the same type
4. from `length a` we can infer `a` is a list of something, e.g. `a ~ [t]`

So from (3) and (4) we can infer that `b ~ [t]` and so we need both `Integral [t]` and `Enum [t]` for some type `t`.

To further elaborate on (3), we know `chain b` is a list, e.g. `[t]` where `t` is the type of `b`. From `a <- chain b` we know `a` has the same type as the elements of `chain b`, i.e. the type of `a` is also `t`.

Comment: @MattVaughan - Just to make it clear, nested list comprehensions are possible, but your types got a bit mixed up.

Comment: When you write a let expression, does it act as an alias and end up having to evaluate it twice, or does it evaluate the expression and then use that value everywhere else. For example, in `[ a | b <- [1..10], let a = chain b, length a > 15 ]` does it have to evaluate `chain b` everywhere it sees `a`?

Comment: It will only be evaluated once.